# How to search for patent payment information

Tags: payment

Usually I check INPADOC legal status on Espacenet for payment info; however, if there isn't any I will check PAIR on USPTO.

I am wondering if there is better way to find more info and more detail about payment status?

Moreover, how to interpret "Designated state"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For European Patent (applications), you can get more detailed payment information in EPregister:
https://register.epo.org/regviewer?lng=en

In particular, there you can also see warnings due to late or non-payment of fees by clicking on "All Documents" in the menu on the left when inspecting a given file.

For an EP, "designated states" are the countries in which the granted patent would eventually be valid. Since there is no real unitary patent (quite yet!), a granted EP will be converted into a bundle of national patents in a selection (or all) of the member states of the European Patent Organisation. See here for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grant_procedure_before_the_European_Patent_Office#Designation_of_States_and_request_for_examination

Also see 1. paragraph here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Patent_Convention

Also see last paragraph here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Patent_Convention#Unified_prosecution_phase

Comment: Thank you, that's a lot information to take in! May I further ask you another question? When I am searching active pharmaceutical ingredient related patents on Espacenet, I enter the ingredient name in title & abstract blank. There may pop up hundreds of data. Is there a function that the result only shows the specific country I want (I want to find TW patent first)?

Answer (score 0):

Tumbs up for above info -- below is just addition to make answer complete

Keep in mind that INPADOC is just a depository and they publish data given by respective patent offices. Most of the time this data may not be updated. Best source is respective patent office.
Also keep in mind that there is reissue / reviival procedure after lapse of patent which is of limited time but eventually can backfire a ignorant researcher.

Comment: So even EPregister isn't a reliable source? I hardly find any documents in EPregister. Another question is: our client showed us TW408127 and TWI333957, two patent related to a drug named Dutasteride. I was wondering how they find and define these two patents. First, the term "dutasteride" doesn't even appear in title, abstract or contents. I know it may be paraphrase with the chemical name or something else. But second, how could they define the patent is exactly claiming "dutasteride"? Thank you for all your helps. :)

Comment: Ep register is best source for European patents but definitely not for tw patents. Their are many source to get patents so client has used one of it.